# How to control QProgressBar with Signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qprogressbar

Pushing the button starts 100 rounds cycle. With `QLabel.setText()` we update `self.label` from inside of scope of `clicked()` function.

Aside from updating `self.label` we would like to update the `progressbar` as well.
But since `progressbar` is a local variable we can't update it from inside of `onClick()` function.

[image]

```
import time

class ProgressBar(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, total=20):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setMinimum(1)
        self.setMaximum(105)        
        self.setTextVisible(True) 

    def set_to_value(self, value):
        self.setValue(value)
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._active=False


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QDialog,self).__init__()

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('idle...')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        progressbar = ProgressBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(progressbar) 

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Process')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        layout.addWidget(button) 

    def onClick(self):
        for i in range(101):
            message = '...processing %s of 100'%i
            self.label.setText(message)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.resize(300, 100)
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `qApp.processEvents()` manually?

Comment: The example doesn't seem to involve threading or other processes...I assume the question title is incorrect? There are other considerations you need to take into account if you are actually using threads.

Comment: @three_pineapples: I just wanted to keep the code in my question as simple as possible. The goal was to find a way to control a widget from outside of the the instance where the widget was declared, from inside of another outside thread or from inside of another outside process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the progress bar as:

```
self.progressbar = ProgressBar(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code declares a local `progressbar` object connected to a custom 'customSignal` using:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), progressbar, QtCore.SLOT("setValue(int)"))`

with four arguments passed to `QtCore.QObject.connect()`.

The first argument `self` is the object that will be emitting the signal. Since the function that will do the "sleep-every-second-processing" is declared under the main `Dialog` instance we pass `self` here.

The second argument is the name of the signal itself: 'customSignal'.

The `progressbar` object is used as third and its method `setValue` as fourth last argument.

[image]

```
class ProgressBar(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QDialog,self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('idle...')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        progressbar = ProgressBar(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), progressbar, QtCore.SLOT("setValue(int)"))

        layout.addWidget(progressbar) 

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Process')
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        layout.addWidget(button) 

    def clicked(self):
        for value in range(101):
            message = '...processing %s of 100'%value
            self.label.setText(message)
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), value)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.resize(300, 100)
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

## --------------------

Here is variation of the same solution except linking to the progressbar method.
    import time

```
class ProgressBar(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def set_to_value(self, value):
        self.setValue(value)
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        return True

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._active=False

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent=None)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('idle...')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        progressbar = ProgressBar(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), progressbar.set_to_value )
        layout.addWidget(progressbar) 

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Process')
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        layout.addWidget(button) 

    def clicked(self):
        for value in range(101):
            message = '...processing %s of 100'%value
            self.label.setText(message)
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), value)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.resize(300, 100)
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

## ======================

This code now links a custom signal to a function referred as Slot in Qt.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import time

class ProgressBar(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def set_to_value(self, value):
        self.setValue(value)
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        return True

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._active=False

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent=None)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('idle...')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        progressbar = ProgressBar(self)
        # QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), progressbar.set_to_value )
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), progressbar, QtCore.SLOT("set_to_value(int)"))

        layout.addWidget(progressbar) 

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Process')
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        layout.addWidget(button) 

    def clicked(self):
        for value in range(101):
            message = '...processing %s of 100'%value
            self.label.setText(message)
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("customSignal(int)"), value)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.resize(300, 100)
    dialog.show()
```